# How to trap user with do-while loop?

Tags: java, do-while

```
String error = "Write a number below, between 1-9;";
int number;
do {
    String userentered = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(error);
    number = Integer.parseInt(userentered);
    if (number < 0 && number > 10) {
        error = "Error";
    }
} while (number > 0 && number < 10);
```

I want to trap the user in this do while loop, until  there have provided the correct answer, e.g. number between 1-9, right now. Right now, when the user types in a letter or leaves the field black and click ok, the optionpane closes but I want it to stay open until the correct input is given. Right now, also if the user types in the correct input it gives them the error message but if there type in a wrong input it closes.

Comment: Your code loops while the entered value is valid. It must loop while the entered value is invalid.

Comment: `number < 0 && number > 10` should be `number < 0 || number > 10` ....right???

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` can throw `NumberFormatException`. You have to catch that inside the loop.

Comment: @NoobEditor I have tried that but it does not work.

Comment: Also a number can't be < 0 and > 10 at the same time. You're really confused between AND and OR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the parseInt method in try-catch block. Also modify the condition to be number < 1 || number > 9. finally you have to initialize the number with invalid value, lets say -1

```
String error = "Write a number below, between 1-9;";
int number = -1;
do {
    try {
        String userentered = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(error);
        number = Integer.parseInt(userentered);
        if (number < 1 || number > 9) {
            error = "Error";
        }
    } catch (HeadlessException | NumberFormatException e) {
        error = "Error";
    }
} while (number < 1 || number > 9);
```

Comment: thanks it works with letters too now but it is now displaying the error message

Comment: Thank you, and thanks everyone else, everything is working now.

Comment: can i ask you a question. Why do we have to initialize the value?

Comment: Try not initializing it, and see what happens.

Comment: Since the method parseInt may throws an exception, so the last statement will be reached with null value for number! this will cause compilation error.

Comment: Hi JB, I tried and it gives me an error so I changed it back

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `while` condition of the `do-while` loop. Currently it is looping if the number is within the range, but your requirement is the exact reverse of it.

```
while (!(number > 0 && number < 10)); // Keep looping if the number is outside the range.
```

Note: The `Integer.parseInt()` will throw a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` if the improper inputs are not handled properly.

Comment: Actually it currently loops no matter what the number is, because every number is > 0 or < 10 (or both).

Comment: Thanks R.J it works now, going to update my code for other people who need help with do while loop

Comment: RJ, now can I add throw Exception?

Comment: @Peter - Do not update your question with the solution. If you do that, this answer makes no sense then. Instead, accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @Peter - Yeah you can add a `try-catch` or a `throws` clause in the method signature, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It's Simple, do while loop  is entry control loop.
so we need to stat from one less value.

```
            String errorMsg = "Write a number below, between 1-9;";
    int number = 0;
    do {
        try {
            String usernum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(errorMsg);
            number = Integer.parseInt(usernum);
            if (number < 1 || number > 9) {
                errorMsg = "Error";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorMsg = "Error";
        }
    } while (number < 1 || number > 9);
```